# Merge/Append txt files line by line when a common word is found in both files

Tags: batch-file, autohotkey

I'm looking for a batch command file (or Autohotkey) solution to help me to merge two huge .txt files that share a common word at the beginning of each line, appending the second part of the line of the second file to the end of each line of the first file, only if the first word in both files is an exact match, outputting the results to a third file.

I looked around for a while and found similar examples, but they all seem to merge everything in pairs, no matter they having matching words or not.

So here's what I'm looking for:

File1.txt contains:

> Ana=134=address=nonoanneo=othertext
>
> Robert=682sd=otherinfo=elseinfo=etc
>
> Richard=Carnameother=dog=glasses
>
> Paula=Home4562-construction=car
>
> Jessica=Koala=6788655=anyothertext=anyothertext

File2.txt contains:

> Ana=Yoga
>
> Robert=Ping-pong
>
> Carlos=Gardening
>
> Richard=Video-games
>
> Jessica=Movies

ExpectedResult.txt

> Ana=134=address=nonoanneo=othertext=Yoga
>
> Robert=682sd=otherinfo=elseinfo=etc=Ping-pong
>
> Richard=Carnameother=dog=glasses=Video-games
>
> Jessica=Koala=6788655=anyothertext=anyothertext=Movies

Notice that neither Paula (File1.txt) or Carlos (File2.txt) are included in the final result, since there's no matching first word in either file.

I got a working solution in autohotkey, but it uses nested loops and it takes almost half an hour to compare about 30.000 lines in each file, so it's not an option :/

I know that the solution is probably a breeze to some of you, so thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: have u tried some using regexp in Notepad++? Maybe even u can create macro for this. Should be something like: put 2 files data into one; order data; find, mark and add matching rows; remove unnecessary data. And this will work very fast (depends on your system), but I would say several min.

Comment: Thank you Darka. I had never used Notepad++, but I'm guessing that if RegEx is the way it would do it, either a batch or AutoHotkey/AutoIt would be able to do it, since they all support RegEx, no?

Comment: Yes you are right. Please look at my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more way using AutoHotkey (AHK_L), See if it works for you

```
SetBatchLines, -1
FileRead, file1, .\GeneratedFiles\Text1.ini
FileRead, file2, .\GeneratedFiles\Text2.ini
f2 := []
loop, parse, File2, `n, `r
    x:=StrSplit(A_LoopField, "="), f2[x.1] := x.2
loop, parse, File1, `n, `r
    if f2[v:=StrSplit(A_LoopField, "=").1]
        R .= A_LoopField "=" f2[v] "`r`n"
f2 := []
FileAppend, % Trim(R, "`r`n"), MergeNPCV.ini
```

Comment: Well, not only this worked flawlessly, but it only took a second or 2 to complete o_O
Your solution is my choice, good sir! Thank you for this clever solution and thank you everyone for your AWESOME input!!! Best online community ever :)

Answer (score 4):

The way to perform a *standard* file merge is when both files are ordered via a common key, so the missed records in any file can be immediately identified by its position in the file. However, in this case no one of the files are ordered, so it is necessary to load one entire file in a memory array.

The Batch file below is a solution for this problem, but the speed of Batch files is affected by the number of memory variables defined, so I can't promise that it will be very fast. I can only hope that it will be faster than the AutoIT solutions...

This method assume that there is just *one record* with the same key in File1.txt.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Load the second file in an array
for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in (File2.txt) do set "w[%%a]=%%b"

rem Process the first file, and merge it with the array
(for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in (File1.txt) do (
   if defined w[%%a] (
      echo %%a=%%b=!w[%%a]!
      set "w[%%a]="
   )
)) > Result.txt
```

**EDIT**: You may try a second test removing the `set "w[%%a]="` line (and the unnecessary parentheses). This may result in a faster execution, depending on the data.

Comment: This is AWESOME, Aacini!!! The whole thing was chewed up and a beautiful, clean result was spit out in mere 2 min 25 seconds in my machine!!!! This is the winner solution so far, but I still have to try the other ones. The reason why I prefer ahk and cmd solutions is that my intention is to create a fully self-contained installer in the future, so the less dependencies the better, especially since the Gui is already built in ahk and it's working pretty good. Thank you SO MUCH! Exciting :)

Comment: I just removed the set "w[%%a]=" line and the time dropped to 1min and 49 seconds! If there's a faster way to do this I will be shocked. More than happy as it is. You sir is a coding magician :)
Thanks a ton!

Edit: minor problem, I looked through the file and I noticed that some lines were unsuccessful, the ones containing "[" and "]" characters in them.
-Kris

Comment: Minor problem, I looked through the file and I noticed that some lines were unsuccessful, the ones containing "[" and "]" characters in them. Also, mere two lines are missing (30022 generated, out of 30024 with the other methods), but I need to investigate which ones to find out why.

Comment: No, your method seems more reliable as well. The missing lines were not in one of the files and should not be merged anyway, so double win! The lines start with only 3 characters "3ds=". That might have something to do with it on other methods. The only remaining problem is that the lines containing "[" and/or "]" are not being merged.

Comment: Lines containing `!` need special handling with delayed expansion active.  Place line 2 (beginning with setlocal) before the second `rem` line and it may help in this case.

Comment: foxidrive, you nailed it! It turns out that the problematic lines had an "!" in them. Good catch!

Comment: A solution can be to do a global replace of every `!` with say `|||||` or something that will not exist in the file, and repeat the global replace afterward (in reverse) to restore the `!` characters.  Another batch file tool called `repl.bat` by dbenham can do this very quickly and it has a `L` literal switch to make this simpler.

Comment: Yep. In fact, the main file being processed is already being parsed from a much larger XML file. That means that is super easy for me to just StringReplace the "!" on the way out and reverse it on the way in. No biggie at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this AutoIT Code :

```
#include <array.au3>

;The handle of the result file (result.txt)
Local $hResultFile = FileOpen(@ScriptDir&"\result.txt", 1)

;Putting each file into memory
$hfile1 = FileOpen(@ScriptDir&"\file1.txt")
$hfile2 = FileOpen(@ScriptDir&"\file2.txt")
$file1 = FileRead($hFile1)
$file2 = FileRead($hFile2)

;Creating an array with eachline of the files

$aFile1 = StringSplit($File1,@LF)
$aFile2 = StringSplit($File2,@LF)

;looping in the array to test each line

For $i = 1 to UBound($aFile1)-1
;Getting the name to test in File2.txt
   $TestName = stringsplit($aFile1[$i],"=")[1]
;Testing if the name exist in File2 and getting the Index in $aFile2 of the finded string
   $Index =_ArraySearch($aFile2,$TestName,-1,-1,-1,-1,3)
;If a matching name is found then writing the new line in result.txt
   if not @error Then
      $Line=StringReplace($aFile1[$i] & "=" & StringSplit($aFile2[$Index],"=")[2],@CR,"")
      FileWriteLine($hResultFile,$Line&@CRLF)
      EndIf
   Next
FileClose($hResultFile)
FileClose($hFile1)
FileClose($hFile2)
```

The output file is `result.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Ok here is my solution:

```
#m::    ; the hotkey
TempFile := "C:\copy\temp.txt"
NewFile := "C:\copy\new.txt"
Run, %comspec% /c copy /Y C:\copy\File1.txt+C:\copy\File2.txt  %TempFile% ; merge all files with extension txt
Loop ;waits for file
{
IfExist, %TempFile%
    Break
Sleep 1000
}
FileRead, Contents, %TempFile%
if not ErrorLevel  ; Successfully loaded.
{
    Sort, Contents
}
Contents := RegExReplace(Contents, "(\r\n|^)([^=]+?)(=[^\r\n]+?)\r\n\2(=[^\r\n]+?(\r\n|$|))", "$1_$2$3$4") ; finds Matching names
Contents := RegExReplace(Contents, "(\r\n|^)[^_][^\r\n]+?(\r\n|$)", "$1$2") ;removes not matching rows
Contents := RegExReplace(Contents, "(\r\n|^)_", "$1") ;removes underscore
Contents := RegExReplace(Contents, "\s\s+", "`r`n") ; removes empty rows
Contents := RegExReplace(Contents, "", "") ; after merge we have this symbol so we can remove it
Contents := RegExReplace(Contents, "^\s+", "") ; remove first empty row
FileAppend, %Contents%, %NewFile%
Contents =  ; Free the memory.
FileDelete, %TempFile%
return
```

Here we have some issue like:

- File1 and File2 must have empty last row
- Only merges second row with same name, the third will be ignored (can be fixed by putting first `RegExReplace` into `Loop` and checking if there is match)
- Not sure about order lines will be merged (File1 row to File2 or File2 to File1)
- If File1 or File2 has 2 same names this will merge them.

Seems works fast.....

Here is a bit changed script, which takes row from File1 and attaches File2 row:

```
#m::    ; the hotkey

NewFile := "C:\copy\new.txt"

FileRead, Contents1, C:\copy\File1.txt
Contents1 := RegExReplace(Contents1, "(\r\n|^)([^=]+?)=", "$1$21=") 

FileRead, Contents2, C:\copy\File2.txt
Contents2 := RegExReplace(Contents2, "(\r\n|^)([^=]+?)=", "$1$22=") 

Contents := Contents1 . "`r`n" . Contents2 . "`r`n"

Contents1 =
Contents2 = 

if not ErrorLevel  ; Successfully loaded.
{
    Sort, Contents
}

Contents := RegExReplace(Contents, "(\r\n|^)([^1=]+?)1(=[^\r\n]+?)\r\n\2(2)", "$1_$2$3") ; finds Matching names
Contents := RegExReplace(Contents, "(\r\n|^)[^_][^\r\n]+?(\r\n|$)", "$1$2") ;removes not matching rows
Contents := RegExReplace(Contents, "(\r\n|^)_", "$1") ;removes underscore
Contents := RegExReplace(Contents, "\s\s+", "`r`n") ; removes empty rows
Contents := RegExReplace(Contents, "^\s+", "") ; remove first empty row
FileAppend, %Contents%, %NewFile%
Contents =  ; Free the memory.

return
```

Comment: Thank you Darka! I'll definitely try it out once I get home tonight. So far the batch solution seem incredibly fast, but I'm open to try anything, so I can learn something in the process. Cheers!

Comment: You know, I tested it and it's INCREDIBLY fast... like, takes SECONDS to process the whole file... WOW! But it's not reliable as it is right now. In some lines, it's inserting the appending text right after the matching word instead of the end of the line. Also, even lines without a matching first word are being included in the output file. Seems like adjustments are necessary in the RegEx parameters, but I can see a HUGE potential for this solution! Really impressive.

Comment: Hey Darka, I was looking at the results of your solution and there are things, as you mentioned, that are not perfect. The main one is that sometimes File1 row to File2 or File2 to File1 is messed up and completely random. Maybe a "if" to force the RegEx to always start with the longest line could do the trick? If so, any pointers on how to approach it? Man, this RegEx thingy is incredibly fast...

Comment: Thanks Darka. The updated script messed up a lot of the lines now :)
But you know what, you bit me with the Regex bug and I'm trying to learn it now. It's a whole little science, but so powerful!
The script you posted is a great starting point and I can see the potential and speed, by far the fastest solution at ridiculous 4 seconds to spit out the file, but unfortunately not usable before some tweaking in the code. Definitely the way to go once the code is reliable though!

Answer (score 2):

Question: Do you know something if your files are sorted regarding the first row? in that case you could really speed up things in a way that you can use two pointers in the two files, like in a mergesort fashion. (But you probably knew that huh? :))

I have to admit i am not so much an ahk pro, so my answer is in Python..
Even worse, I couldnt test with huge files as you seem to need.

But anyways i thought i give it a shot and it maybe even helps someone, so here is my solution:

```
f1 = 'File1.txt'
f2 = 'File2.txt'
f3 = 'File3.txt'
with open(f1, 'r') as file1, open(f2, 'r') as file2, open(f3, 'w') as file3:
    words1 = dict()
    words2 = dict()
    for line in file1:
        k,e = line.split('=',1)
        e = e.rstrip('\n')
        if k in words1:
            words1[k] += '=' + e
        else:
            words1[k] = '=' + e

    for line in file2:
        k,e = line.split('=',1)
        e = e.rstrip('\n')
        if k in words2:
            words2[k] += '=' + e
        else:
            words2[k] = '=' + e

    words = set(words1).intersection(set(words2))

    for w in words:
        file3.write(w + words1[w] + words2[w] + '\n')
```

maybe you need to check whether '\n' is indeed your lineending, but thats only some os.* stuff..

Comment: Thank you silentbat. I should definitely try some python. I know how powerful it can be. I'm just a newbie when it comes to coding :)

Answer (score 1):

SachaDee,
thank you SO much for taking the time to reply.

The good news is that the script you provided works perfectly and straight out of the box. Also, I got to learn a little AutoIt.

The bad news is that it's very slow to be used with the large files I'm dealing with.
In fact, I tried my old script which has a nested loop in it and I also coded a variation of it, using SplitString and a simple loop instead of two parsing loops.

Here are the results:

On 30.000 registers to be compared, generating a 3.5Mb text file as output:

Original script: about 18 minutes

My new script: about 14 minutes

AutoIt script: about 31 minutes

So, they all produce the same output, but the difference in time consumed is HUGE!
The AutoIt script started pretty fast, cranking many bytes at times, way faster than ahk... but it got stuck in the middle of the file where there's a lot of repetitive text and slowed down a lot, while both ahk scripts continued in the very same pace.

What puzzles me is that I've seen someone managing to merge the exact same files in about 1.5 minute!!! No idea what he is using for it, but looks like voodoo or black magic of some kind :)

I'll post my fastest one so far, so people might want to try it. It's probably very fast for smaller files:

```
#SingleInstance Force
#MaxThreads 255
#MaxMem 4095
#MaxThreadsBuffer On
#ListLines Off
SetBatchLines, -1
SetKeyDelay, -1

FileRead, XMLRead, .\GeneratedFiles\Text1.ini
StringSplit, XMLLines, XMLRead, `n
FileRead, CVRead, .\GeneratedFiles\Text2.ini
Loop,
{
    GameLine := XMLLines%A_Index%
    If Instr(GameLine, "=")
    {
    StringSplit, GameInfo, GameLine, "=",

    Loop, parse, CVRead, `n
    {
        StringSplit, CVReadB, A_LoopField, "=",
        If (GameInfo1 = CVReadB1)
        {
        StringTrimRight, GameLine, GameLine, 1
        MergeResult = %GameLine%=%CVReadB2%

        FileAppend, %MergeResult%, MergeNPCV.ini
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post updates in your question. You can also post a new question instead.